# How to calculate expected angular momentum for $d_{x^2 - y^2}$ orbital

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, orbitals

I know that the expectation values of $L_x, L_y, L_z$ are $0$ for a $d_{x^2 - y^2}$ orbital, but how is this done using algebra?

In other words, can someone show me how $\langle d_{x^2 - y^2}|\hat{L_z}| d_{x^2 - y^2}\rangle =0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the averages as usual,
$$
\langle \Psi_{d_{x^2-y^2}} | {\hat L}_k | \Psi_{d_{x^2-y^2}} \rangle = \int{dV \; \Psi^*_{d_{x^2-y^2}}({\vec r}) {\hat L}_k \Psi_{d_{x^2-y^2}} ({\vec r}) }
$$
using the differential expressions for the angular momentum components ${\hat L}_k$. Because the orbital separates into a radial and an angular part, $$\Psi_{d_{x^2-y^2}}({\vec r}) = R_{d_{x^2-y^2}}(r) Y_{d_{x^2-y^2}}(\theta, \phi)$$the best way to do this is in spherical coordinates, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_operator) and keep in mind that $L_\pm = L_x \pm iL_y$.

But for $L_z$ it's even simpler, because in spherical coordinates it reads
$$
L_z = - i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}
$$
while the angular part of the orbital [reads](https://winter.group.shef.ac.uk/orbitron/AOs/3d/equations.html)
$$
Y_{d_{x^2-y^2}}(\theta, \phi) \sim \frac{x^2 - y^2}{r^2} = \sin^2\theta \cos^2\phi - \sin^2\theta \sin^2\phi = \sin^2\theta
$$
Which means ${\hat L}_z Y_{d_{x^2-y^2}}(\theta, \phi) =0$, or else that $Y_{d_{x^2-y^2}}(\theta, \phi)$ is an eigenfunction of ${\hat L}_z$ for eigenvalue $m=0$.

You may also want to read on [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Orbital_angular_momentum).

Comment: But how would I find the expected value for $L_x$ and $L_y$?

Comment: If you are a beginner, use the 1st eq. in the answer: in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_operator#Orbital_angular_momentum_in_spherical_coordinates you can find expressions for the two operators $L_\pm$ from which you can calculate $L_x$ and $L_y$ in spherical coordinates. Or see pg.321 in https://faculty.washington.edu/seattle/physics227/reading/reading-24-25.pdf. Then here, https://winter.group.shef.ac.uk/orbitron/AOs/3d/equations.html, you find expressions for the orbital, they should be already normalized. Plug everything in the expectation value integral, do the math.

Comment: But if you know a few things about angular momentum and its eigenfunctions, see all of https://faculty.washington.edu/seattle/physics227/reading/reading-24-25.pdf, you can use the fact that the orbital is an eigenfunction of $L_z$ for $m=0$, which we can denote $|m=0\rangle$. Then you take advantage of the fact that $L_\pm |m=0\rangle \sim |m = \pm 1\rangle$, and that $\langle m=0 | m = \pm 1\rangle = 0$ (orthogonality), so it must be that $\langle m=0| L_\pm | m=0 \rangle = 0$. Which also means $\langle m=0| L_x | m=0 \rangle =  \langle m=0| L_y | m=0 \rangle = 0$.